# Generated markdown file with rake post command

Tags: ruby, rake, blogs, jekyll

I am deploying my github blog using jekyll-bootstrap.I try to modify Rakefile to change the result of $rake post title="test" and then this command will generate a file named test.md（without date） in _posts directory,but unfortunately,when I run 
    $jekyll serve 
locally,it seems that jekyll do not think test.md is an available post,what shoul I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want it's custom url for your posts.
Leave alone the rake task, because the final post filename is generated in accordance with a permalinks pattern see [permalinks documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/)

By default you posts are generated following the default pattern /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title/index.html

If you want to change this pattern, in your _config.yml, use permalink key :

```
permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/filename.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but what I exactly want is the filename without date,not the permalinks,permalinks just change its urlL:）

Comment: But you cannot change the filename pattern in _post/. See the doc http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#creating-post-files. I really can't understand why you want to change working files filename that are not part of the visible files (the one in _site), it really seems unnecessary.

Comment: As you know,the filename is always looks like this:
2011-07-31-1.md
2011-08-31-2.md
2012-09-12-3.textile
When I trying to use vim to open 2.md,I will press tab for 2 times in shell,I just want to make is possible to use less tab:),you are right,it is a hit or miss for me,too,but if there is an alternative or solution,why I don`t take a shot.